# Can't get keyListener to work while Timer is running

Tags: timer, keylistener

Hello people of stack overflow, my program has a driver class Frogger(), a JPanel class that calculates everything, pulls together all the necessary panels, and implements keyListener called FroggerPanel(), and another JPanel class that draws everything based on the elements in FroggerPanel() called FroggerDisplayPanel().

Here's a pastebin with the full code: http://pastebin.com/Axrbjej6.

The keyListener works exactly as it should when the Timer isn't started, but as soon as it starts it wont respond at all!

This is where the keyListener is added and focused on in the Frogger() class:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{
    frame = new JFrame("CS125 Frogger");
    Frogger startPanel = new Frogger();
    FroggerPanel panel = new FroggerPanel();

    frame.addKeyListener(panel);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is the stepGame() method in FroggerPanel() that is called when the timer delay expires, its mostly concerned with moving all the cars; the Frog Rectangle in the setLocations() method is what I need to respond to the keyListener:

```
    private int current_x_step = 0;
private int lane_bounds = 0;
private int new_pos = 0;
private void stepGame() {

    for (int i = 0; i < laneAmt; i++) {
        if(i == 0 || i % 2 == 0){
            current_x_step = X_STEP_SIZE;
            lane_bounds = display.getWidth()+rUnit;
            new_pos = -rUnit;
        }else if((i-1) == 0 || (i-1) % 2 == 0){
            current_x_step = -X_STEP_SIZE;
            lane_bounds = -rUnit;
            new_pos = DISPLAY_DIM + rUnit;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < cars.get(i).size(); j++){
            cars.get(i).get(j).x += current_x_step;                     
            if (cars.get(i).get(j).x == lane_bounds) {                      
                cars.get(i).get(j).x = new_pos;             
            }
            if(cars.get(i).get(j).intersects(Frog)){
                timer.stop();
                startPause.setText("Retry?");
                break;
            } 
        }
    }           
    display.setLocations(cars, Frog);   
    if(Frog.y == 0){
        stepLevel();            
    }
}
```

This is the keyListener code thats in the FroggerPanel() class:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_W: Frog.y -= rUnit; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_S: Frog.y += rUnit; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_A: Frog.x -= rUnit; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_D: Frog.x += rUnit; break;         
    }
    display.setLocations(cars, Frog);
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_W: Frog.y -= rUnit; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_S: Frog.y += rUnit; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_A: Frog.x -= rUnit; break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_D: Frog.x += rUnit; break;             
    }   
    display.setLocations(cars, Frog);
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks for the help!